# How to remove duplicate values using simpleXML in PHP

Tags: php, xml

Good day everyone.

I want to create a dropdown menu for tool categories and remove all the duplicates that appear in the 'category' tag before displaying it.

So far, I have:

```
<select id="tool" name="category">
     <?php                  
        $tools = simplexml_load_file('tools.xml');
            
        $categoryArray = array();
            
        foreach($tools as $tool) {
          if(!in_array((string)$tool->category, $categoryArray)) {
             $categoryArray[] = (string)$tool->category;
          }
        }
        print_r("<option value='".$categoryArray."'>".$categoryArray."</option>");                   
     ?>
</select>
```

However, when I run this code the categories don't appear, and instead I only get an "Array" text in my dropdown.

How can I solve this issue?

For reference, this is what my **tools.xml** looks like:

```
<tools>
    <tool type="..." web-based="..." free="...">
       <name>...</name>
       <description>...</description>
       <url>...</url>
       <subjects>...</subjects>
       <creators>...</creators>
       <category>Office tool</category>  
       <price>...</price>
   </tool>
</tools>
```

Comment: Try `print_r($tool->category)` to see what is the content. Maybe `$tool->category[0]` would be the solution.

Comment: Well if you recieve an array then its obviously an array? Use `echo "<option value='" . htmlentities($tool['name']) . "'>" . htmlentities($tool['name']) . "</option>";` instead of `print_r("<option value='".$categoryArray."'>".$categoryArray."</option>");`. And why are you using `print_r` anyhow? Its for debugging. You could have figured that out by yourself if you did dump the whole `$tools`-array with `print_r($tools)` (before you create the select obviously).

Comment: I was struggling with trying to figure out how to make it work with a dropdown, since I was successfully able to run the code without doing the select. I'm still a beginner in PHP therefore I didn't quite understand what I was doing wrong until now. Thank you for your reply!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment, you try and print the `<option>` element after creating an array of all of the categories.  Instead include it in the loop when you add a new category...

```
    foreach($tools as $tool) {
        if(!in_array((string)$tool->category, $categoryArray)) {
           $categoryArray[] = (string)$tool->category;
           print_r("<option value='".(string)$tool->category."'>".(string)$tool->category."</option>");          
      }
    }
```

Comment: Now when I do this, I get 'Array', 'Array', 'Array', 'Array', 'Array', 'Array' in my dropdown instead of getting the category names

Comment: Are you using `(string)$tool->category`?

Comment: For some reason I completely missed that part, my apologies! It works perfectly, thank you very much. :)